# Flatten array using iteration + stack in python

Tags: python, stack, iteration

I am trying to implement a flatten array function using an iterative solution with stacks, not recursion. I will now show you my progress and some of my logic but I can't quite figure it out fully to finish it:

```
def flatten(l):
    stack = []
    result = []
    stack.append(l[0])
    while len(stack) > 0:
        currentItem = stack.pop()
        if type(currentItem) == list:
            for i in currentItem[::-1]:
                stack.append(i)
        else:
            result.append(currentItem)
    return result

#Example input and output 1: flatten([1, 2, 3, 4]) => [1]
#Example input and output 2: flatten([[12, [14]], 45, 13, 4, 9]) => [12, 14]
```

My biggest problem is figuring out a way to continue on to the correct next item of the list after adding a normal element. I need to add something to the stack to keep the while loop flowing

Comment: What is the current output of your code?

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I edited the post to include two examples of my outputs

Comment: You need to initialize the stack with the entire original list, not just `l[0]`

Comment: `stack = l[::-1]`

Comment: @Barmar Oh wow. It works when I initialize the stack with `stack=l`. That was stupid  on my side, I can't believe I didn't see that one :D Thank you!

Comment: You should copy the stack if you don't want this to modify it. `stack = l[:]`

Comment: Yup, you're right @Barmar. Its just a practice problem now so it doesn't make a difference. Thank you :)